# Unexpected "False" in console when calling print through qt button click

Tags: python, pyqt, functools

I have a clickable qt button:

```
window.my_button.clicked.connect(functools.partial(print, "Clicked!"))
```

I'd expect this to print `Clicked!\n` to console when I press the button.
Instead it prints `Clicked! False\n`.

Why does it do this and how do I change it to the expected behavior?

Comment: This is explained in the [`partial` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial): "If more arguments are supplied to the call, they are appended to args." Since `print()` accepts any number of arguments, there's where you get that further value; as you can see from the docs about the [`clicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) signal, it **always** has a `checked` argument (which is used for checkable buttons). If you want to ignore that, use a lambda or a wrapper (with proper keyword arguments if any is needed).

Comment: Since the lambda worked well, I'll leave this example here, should anyone stumble upon the issue in the future:
`window.start_camera_button.clicked.connect(lambda: print("Clicked!"))`